# footer text highlights blue in IE10?

Tags: html, css, text, colors, footer

Please could someone troubleshoot this strange problem!!!!
For some reason in internet explorer 10 when the text in the footer is highlighted with the mouse it goes blue?

I just do not understand why? but i bet it is something really simple that i am missing!

The rest of the text on the page highlights in a normal way 
but WHYY does the footer text do this!!!!

Please help anyone, i have put the link because i truly do not know where the problem is!

Here is the web page: http://www.everyday/

Comment: Are you able to post a screen shot for those who don't have IE 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE does this because your footer color is too light.

If you make the footer color black or a dark gray like #787878 it will highlight normally

Comment: Thankyou soo much!! I knew it was something ridiculous like that, you have saved me hours of confusion